# What does the 'enabled' property do in a SecretAttributes object?

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

In the documentation for [`Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/SecretAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/secrets#SecretAttributes), there is no explanation for what the `enabled` property does. The documentation simply states

> Determines whether the object is enabled.

What is the difference between an enabled and not-enabled object, and if the naive answer is the correct one, why would anyone need a not-enabled `SecretAttribute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does exactly that. why would any one want that, well, security reasons? disabling outdated secret without deleting it?

Comment: It makes sense to disable it later, but it's not intuitive as a parameter for creation of new secrets.

Comment: well, its the same api endpoint, how would it discern between new and existing object? any why?

Comment: You're quite right, it didn't occur to me it was an idempotent endpoint. Still quite new to the ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

The `enabled` property does exactly what is said, eg. allows or disallows if a secret can be retrieved by a service consuming the secrets through the azure key vault.

### Why is this useful?

- When rotating secrets, one can add the new secrets but keep them disabled until rotation (eg. similar to the `nbf` and `exp`)
- Keeping backup credentials in the keystore (eg. many Azure Services have two connection strings). When the primary secret is compromised, rotating the secrets gets easier
- Quickly disable secrets that have been compromised